# OpenGL 4.0 in C# panel or WPF WinFormsHost (VS 2022)

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

I want to put OpenGL inside a panel in C# Winform or I want to put it inside a WinFormsHost panel in WPF but I always get an error. When I look at old examples, they don't work because the versions are outdated. Just an example running OpenGL's main window inside a panel would suffice for me. Can I find such an example with the current OpenGL4.0?

Comment: Please show your code and which error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Eror:
No device or rendering context available!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBBUA.png)

```
namespace Yontem2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private static int widthEkran = 300, heightEkran = 300;

        static int panel;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // create an OpenGL window
            Glut.glutInit();
            Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);
            Glut.glutInitWindowSize(Width, Height);

            Glut.glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
            //glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);

            Glut.glutCreateWindow("");
            //panel = Glut.glutCreateWindow("");
            //Glut.glutCreateSubWindow(panel, 10, 10, 300, 300);
            

            // provide the Glut callbacks that are necessary for running this tutorial
            Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
            Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);

            Glut.glutMainLoop();   
            
            simpleOpenGlControl1.Refresh();
        }

        public static void OnDisplay()
        {

        }

        public static void OnRenderFrame()
        {
            // set up the OpenGL viewport and clear both the color and depth bits
            Gl.Viewport(0, 0, widthEkran, heightEkran);
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
        }




    }
}
```